# Too many connection to SQLite databse using sqlalchemy cause Python scirpts fails

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

In my Python script, I use sqlachemy to connect to a sqlite databse. Many scripts failed with the error message

```
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) disk I/O error
...
[SQL: SELECT headline, body, NYTime, subjects, country, pid, ric, mic, ticker       FROM news       WHERE            sector LIKE '%Energy%'       AND            ticker LIKE  (?)       AND            NYTime BETWEEN (?) AND (?)]
[parameters: ('%CRC%', datetime.date(2006, 4, 16), datetime.date(2006, 4, 19))]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

When I re-ran the script again, the job complete successfully. I guess the script failed because too many scripts tried to access the same database. My questions are 1) Is my guess right? 2) How can I prevent it from happening?

Edit: I am trying to read from the database. My code are as follows

```
db_dir = 'database_directory'
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///" + db_dir + "database_name.db")
sql = "SELECT headline, body, NYTime, subjects, country, ticker\
       FROM news\
       WHERE\
            sector LIKE '%Energy%'\
       AND\
            ticker LIKE  (?)\
       AND\
            NYTime BETWEEN (?) AND (?)"
for i in np.arange(len(df_2006_health)):
    event_date = df_2006_health.Date.iloc[i]
    sta_date = event_date - timedelta(days=1)
    end_date = event_date + timedelta(days=2)
    symbol = '%' + df_2006_health.Symbols.iloc[i] + '%'
    if i == 0:
        df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine, params=(symbol,
                                                    sta_date, end_date))
```

Comment: Are you trying to read from or write to the database? (that is, this is not a yes/no question, I'm asking if the operation(s) that fail are read-operations or if they are write-operations)

Comment: There are at least [26 different reasons to get an ioerror](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html). I don't know how to get extended errors in Python but that would help narrow it down

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I'm trying to read from the database.